# Selecting all columns from row with specific max value

Tags: sql-server, select, greatest-n-per-group, sql-server-2019

Imagine that I have the following table:

| ItemCode | WhsCode | MinStock | MaxStock | AvgPrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01 | 1 | 4 | 600 |
| 123 | 02 | 0 | 1 | 200 |
| 512 | 01 | 0 | 2 | 100 |
| 489 | 01 | 0 | 6 | 50 |
| 489 | 02 | 2 | 7 | 72 |
| 489 | 03 | 5 | 10 | 80 |
| 489 | 04 | 1 | 4 | 65 |
| 258 | 01 | 2 | 5 | 45 |

I want to select the row with `MAX(AvgPrice)` for each item, only from warehouses 01 and 02 (WhsCode).

So the result that I want should look like:

| ItemCode | WhsCode | MinStock | MaxStock | AvgPrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01 | 1 | 4 | 600 |
| 512 | 01 | 0 | 2 | 100 |
| 489 | 02 | 2 | 7 | 72 |
| 258 | 01 | 2 | 5 | 45 |

What I tried, in my original code, was:

```
SELECT T0."ItemCode", T3."MinStock", T3."MaxStock", T3."AvgPrice"
FROM OITM T0
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
            MAX(AvgPrice) AS AvgPrice,
            ItemCode,
            MinStock,
            MaxStock 
FROM OITW 
WHERE WhsCode = '01' OR WhsCode = '02' 
GROUP BY ItemCode,MinStock,MaxStock) T3 
ON T0."ItemCode" = T3."ItemCode"
```

But, since I'm also grouping by MinStock and MaxStock, of course I'll have repeated values for each item, because MinStock and MaxStock are almost never the same for each WhsCode.

So what I want to select is ItemCode, MinStock and MaxStock ONLY for the row with the `MAX(AvgPrice)`.

Dialect used is SQL Server 2019. I'm very new to SQL and couldn't find the answer here in an existing post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to filter to just one row per group.

The `PARTITION BY` functions like a `GROUP BY`, except that it does not merge rows, the result is calculated on every row. We then filter it afterwards.

If you want to include tied results then switch to `DENSE_RANK()`.

```sql
SELECT T0."ItemCode", T3."MinStock", T3."MaxStock", T3."AvgPrice"

FROM OITM T0

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemCode ORDER BY AvgPrice DESC) AS rn
            AvgPrice,
            ItemCode,
            MinStock,
            MaxStock 
    FROM OITW 
    WHERE WhsCode = '01' OR WhsCode = '02' 
) T3 
ON T0."ItemCode" = T3."ItemCode" AND T3.rn = 1
```

---

You may find an `APPLY` faster or slower, depending on the exact query.

In an `APPLY` the whole subquery is (logically) run for every row of the outer query. You can reference outer columns, and therefore correlate it to the outer tables, there is no join condition as such.

If you add `TOP` you can then also add `ORDER BY`.

```sql
SELECT T0."ItemCode", T3."MinStock", T3."MaxStock", T3."AvgPrice"

FROM OITM T0

OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1)    -- add WITH TIES if you want tied results
            AvgPrice,
            ItemCode,
            MinStock,
            MaxStock 
    FROM OITW T3
    WHERE (T3.WhsCode = '01' OR T3.WhsCode = '02')
        AND T0."ItemCode" = T3."ItemCode"
    ORDER BY AvgPrice DESC
) T3
```

Note the movement of the join condition and the ordering to the inside, and correct bracketing of the `OR`. Also be careful to always specify the table for each column

---

I suggest you choose better aliases [than `T0` and `T3`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)